# Dealing with Boolean value across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

After spending weeks doing analysis on my dataset, I come to realise something fishy that could actually impact the accuracy of my analysis (too bad).

In my table `segments` containing user's trip segments splitted by user's travel mode, such that each segment has true value on its corresponding travel mode, I realised that some segments actually are having true values for more than one travel mode. This could be errors from users' annotation, for example:

```
SELECT trip_id, segment_id, true_foot, true_bike, true_bus, true_car, true_metro 
FROM segments 
WHERE trip_id=533888 limit 10;
 trip_id | segment_id | true_foot | true_bike | true_bus | true_car | true_metro 
---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+------------
  533888 |         55 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         53 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         51 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         49 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         47 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         45 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         43 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         41 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         37 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
  533888 |         35 | t         | f         | f        | t        | f
(10 rows)
```

In this case, the segment was annotated for both `foot` and `car` mode.

I'm left with no option than:

1. get the total number of such segments (if they aren't many, skipped them in my filtering)
2. somehow manually check with the users' to verify mode per segment (worst scenario: time consuming, underreporting, error prone).

How do I get the count of segments with more than one travel mode?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find the prefix `true_` for a boolean column highly confusing. I typically choose `is_` or `was_` or `has_` depending on what it actually contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `boolean` to `integer` and then count the rows that have `true` in more than one column:

```
select count(*)
from segments
where (true_foot::integer + true_bike::integer + true_bus::integer + true_car::integer + true_metro::integer) > 1
```

Comment: @horse_with_no_name but it has to be at least 2

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that.